# Splitting of a string with spaces resulting in string corruption

Tags: c++

I have a string "My name is: Betty/G". I have to extract Betty/G out of this string for which I have written the following code:

```
std::string str; //"My name is: Betty/G"
char sep = ' ';
std::vector<std::string> token;
for(size_t p=0, q=0; p!=str.npos; p=q)
{
    std::string final = str.substr(p+(p!=0), (q=str.find(sep, p+1))-p-(p!=0));
    token.push_back(final);
}

for(std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator z = token.begin();z!=token.end();++z) 
    std::cout<<":"<<*z<<":"<<std::endl;
```

When I printed the string individually, I get the following output:

```
:My: 

:name:

:is::

:Betty/G
```

There is no ":" after the G character which means the last string is getting corrupted or something weird is happening to it.

I am trying to capture the last string(Betty/G) as follows:

```
int count = token.size();
int len,n;
n=count;
char slsName[30];
len = token[--n].size();
strcpy(slsName,token[--count].c_str());
slsName[len]='\0';
printf("length is %d\n",len);
```

But the length of the string it is printing is 8 whereas it should be 7(Betty/G). Also I tried to remove empty spaces and then check the length, it is still 8. There is no empty space after the last character in the string.

Can anyone please suggest what might be the problem?

Comment: It would be much simpler if you use `std::istringstream`.

Comment: Is there maybe a newline afterwards, such that the colon ends up on the next line?

Comment: Could you print the original string before the splitting, just to be sure?

Comment: Before splitting the string is "My name is: Betty/G"

Comment: Why didn't you just do the traditional "string::find_first_of" loop, instead of the hard to read and scary `str.substr(p+(p!=0), (q=str.find(sep, p+1))-p-(p!=0));` ?

Comment: Why are you mixing types, such as adding and subtracting a Boolean to/from a pointer?

Comment: I don't see the same output.  The last line does end with a colon: https://ideone.com/lHKCap

Comment: Actually this string varies. And I need to extract the name only from the string. So the only way to extract this name would be to split the string which is separated by ' '.

Comment: Look at the variation 4) of this function: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find_last_of/  From your description, you're looking for the last space character in the string, and from there, extracting the text.

Comment: I printed each character of the string and to my surprise , after successfully printing all the characters: character no 1: M, character no 2: y, so on and the last one is character no 20: .

Answer (score 1):

The code runs fine on MSVC 2013.
You would be better off using Boost Tokenizer.